# How to get value from Bootstrap's botton?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

Hi Bootstrap buttons are very beautiful, but How could I get the value which the user click or enter?

ie. for the check boxes.

```
<label class="checkbox inline">
  <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="option1"> 1
</label>
<label class="checkbox inline">
  <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox2" value="option2"> 2
</label>
<label class="checkbox inline">
  <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox3" value="option3"> 3
</label>
```

If I use the PHP, could I get the values to the next page? How?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried give same same to checkboxex and handle it at phpside? 
like;

HTML

```
<form .....
    <label class="checkbox inline">
      <input name="mycheckboxes[]" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="option1"> 1
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox inline">
      <input name="mycheckboxes[]" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox2" value="option2"> 2
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox inline">
      <input name="mycheckboxes[]" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox3" value="option3"> 3
    </label>
```

PHP

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

Comment: hi thanks for replying, if I use these codes, and add a submit button at bottom, how do I get the value at the next page? like if i use ` method = 'post'` in the form action, how to I set the `$value = $_POST['value']` in the next page? Thanks

Comment: You can see at dump, $_POST['mycheckboxes'] is an array which contains values you chekced.

Comment: I am sorry how to show them? I use `<?php
 $array = $_POST['mycheckboxes']
 foreach($array as $key => $value)
 {
  echo $key." has the value". $value;
 }
?>` But appear syntax error... could you help me? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Give it a meaningful name.
For a form like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="gender" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="male"> male
<input type="checkbox" name="gender" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="female"> female
```

You would simply do:

```
if (isset($_POST['gender']))
{
    $user_gender = $_POST['gender']; // would equal either "male" or "female"
}
```

Or a shortcut:

```
$user_gender = isset($_POST['gender']) && $_POST['gender'] == "male"  ? "male" : "female";
```

Happy coding. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi thanks for helping but I am so confused, where to put this code? in the beginning page or the next page? Thanks

Comment: The first block of code goes inside your HTML file, between <form> and </form> tags. The second (or the third, they are the same...) goes into your PHP file, that the form is being submitted to. For example: <form action="welcome.php" method="post"> would send form data to "welcome.php", after the submit button is pressed.